# Using the angular datepicker with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-bootstrap

I'm trying to write something that lets me edit records with dates in them, I have this inside my table:

```
        <tr ng-repeat="event in eventFixtures track by $index">
            <td>{{event.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="input-group">
                            <input type="text"
                                   class="form-control"
                                   ng-model="event.date"
                                   is-open="fixture{{$index}}popup"
                                   ng-click="openFixturePopup($index)"/>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

However when I go to click on one of the input boxes the datepicker doesn't show up.

The open function is here:

```
$scope.openFixturePopup = function(fixture) {
    $scope["fixture"+fixture+"popup"] = true;
};
```

The variables are delcared like so:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $scope["fixture"+i+"popup"] = false;
    }
```

From having the values of the variables be printed out above the table, they are being changed and if I create an input that is linked to a specific fixture popup e.g. like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text"
                   class="form-control"
                   uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                   ng-model="testDate"
                   is-open="fixture0popup"
                   ng-click="openFixturePopup(0)"/>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works fine.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a hunch that trying to use interpolation for a variable name is what is throwing this off. I tried numerous things like `$scope[dynamicVarName]`, `$scope.$eval([dynamicVarName])`, and others to no avail. I can't say for certain that is your issue, but I think I found a solution that you can try.

Set an `isOpen` flag on your event and look at that, rather than creating a bunch of scope variables for state. This is also advantageous because if the index changes, the open state moves with the array element, so there is less chance that you get invalid states.

Here's what the code could look like:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.eventFixtures = [
    {name: "1", date: "1-1-01"},
    {name: "2", date: "2-2-02"},
    {name: "3", date: "3-3-03"},
    {name: "4", date: "4-4-04"},
    {name: "5", date: "5-5-05"}
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="event in eventFixtures track by $index">
      <td>{{event.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
      <td>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="text"
                     class="form-control"
                     ng-model="event.date"
                     is-open="{{event.isOpen}}"
                     ng-blur="event.isOpen = false;"
                     ng-focus="event.isOpen = true;"/>
              isOpen? {{event.isOpen || false}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! with a small edit:
`
                                <input type="text"
                                       class="form-control"
                                       uib-datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy"
                                       ng-model="event.date"
                                       is-open="event.isOpen"
                                       ng-click="event.isOpen = true;"/>

`

However I do have a new issue now which is the date doesn't show up in the box when it first loads, it does when I select a new one though which is odd... Thanks though!

Comment: @MysteriousWaffle I'm curious about the date not showing up when it first loads.. Could you create a new question and replicate the issue? I've never used angular-bootstrap or the datepicker (I use jQueryUI) so I am not familiar with what all needs to be included to get the functionality, but I can always poke around and tinker with a demo to make it work.

Comment: Done:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41515151/date-not-showing-up-in-angular-bootstrap-datepicker